# Need insight in writing a Shell for Operating System course

Tags: linux, shell, unix, computer-science

I have a few questions, the assignment can be seen here: http://www.cs.uic.edu/~i385/

These questions do NOT entail you giving me coding answers, rather questions so that i can understand the assignment better.

1. I have read this document a few times now and NOWHERE do i see a list of commands I need to implement. Is there a small amount of shell commands? If so, where can i see a comprehensive list of them. If there is a ton, then is this program supposed to emulate a shell where it takes your input, parses it and then passes it to the actual operating system?? If this is the case, can someone link me what function I would use to accomplish this?
2. The list on the linked page where it talks about commands such as Fork and Exec and man pages, these are functions that I'm to use in the actual code so that my program does its job properly, correct?
3. There is a segment in the above assignment link that reads as such:

   > Record user and system time of each child as it terminates. These
   >   should be reported for  individual children as they complete, and a
   >   full history should be available by typing “stats”.  The `wait4`
   >   system call will return the desired information for a particular
   >   waited-for child.  See the man page for `getrusage` for a full
   >   description of the `rusage` data structure.*

   I'm specifically curious about this "user" that we're supposed to
   record, is this the actual login name of the individual logged into
   the machine, or some sort of user name we take at the start of the
   shell?
4. I found this on Cornell's site, pseudo code for a shell, it reads as such:

.

```
int
main(int argc, char * * argv) {
    while (1) {
        int childPid;
        char * cmdLine;

        printPrompt();

        cmdLine = readCommandLine(); //or GNU readline("");

        cmd = parseCommand(cmdLine);

        record command in history list(GNU readline history ? )

        if (isBuiltInCommand(cmd)) {
            executeBuiltInCommand(cmd);
        } else {
            childPid = fork();
            if (childPid == 0) {
                executeCommand(cmd); //calls execvp  

            } else {
                if (isBackgroundJob(cmd)) {
                    record in list of background jobs
                } else {
                    waitpid(childPid);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The logic flow above makes sense to me but I'm a bit lost on these things:

1. What does it mean by built in command?
2. And if it's not "built in" then how can the program know what to do anyways?
3. And finally, what is a background job?

Answer (score 1):

(1) You don't need a list of commands.  The shell does essentially the same thing for all external commands.  See `exec`family of system calls.  OK, built-in shell commands are a little different but I didn't see anything on that in your assignment.

(2) Yes, the homework assignment lists a bunch of system calls and C functions.  You will probably need to use all of them somewhere.

(3) It doesn't seem to be asking you about specific user accounts.  By 'user' they just mean whoever is running your shell i.e. what are the usage statistics for the processes (the "commands") you are running.  See `getrusage`.

(4) I very quickly scanned the assignment and didn't see anything there about built-ins or backgrounds processes.  Unless you know otherwise don't worry about it now as they will likely be parts of future assignments.

Honestly, if you are this lost and your assignment is due in two days you really have your work cut out for you.

Comment: Actually you are asked to implement background processes but it gives you some valid hints.